# App crashes with a null variable

Tags: objective-c, null, crash, nsstring, unrecognized-selector

I have  a probelm with a String Variable that appears as null.

```
NSLog(@"rate : %@",_rate);     //-->       rate : <null>
```

The app crashes when I try:

```
if ([_rate length]== 0)    //app crash
```

with message:
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

The strange thing is that using:

```
 if (_rate == nil) and     if (_rate == NULL)
```

variable it seems not nill or null.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `_rate` is an instance of `NSNull`.

```
if (rate == [NSNull null]) {
    // It's set to "NSNull null"
} else {
    // It's a value you can work with
}
```

To avoid the warning (since `rate` is an `NSString`) you can do:

```
if ([rate isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
```

Comment: Tx. Apps not crashes now, although  a warning appears "comparision of distinc pointer types ('NSString' * ') ans NSNull*".